# Internal server with MTGOX api

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest, hmac, bitcoin

I have a problem calling the MTGox HTTP api v2.
I wrote a sendrequest function to generally handle all my requests.
It works great for MONEY/INFO or MONEY/ORDERS but I get a 500 internal server error when i try  methods MONEY/ORDER/QUOTE or MONEY/ORDER/ADD.

It seems like when the post_data contains anything besides the nonce, it goes wrong.
What do I have to do to solve this?

The sendrequest function:

```
private string sendRequest(string action, NameValueCollection query)
    {

        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc.Add("nonce", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
        nvc.Add(query);

        String post_data = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < nvc.Count; i++)
        {
            post_data += "&";
            post_data += nvc.Keys[i];
            post_data += "=";
            post_data += nvc[i];
        }
        post_data = post_data.Substring(1);


        action = "BTCEUR/money/" + action;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sBasePath + action);
        action += "\0"+post_data;
        req.Method = "POST";

        HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(GetBytes(action));
        hmac.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);
        String sign = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(action)), Base64FormattingOptions.None);


        req.Headers.Add("Rest-Key", apikey);
        req.Headers.Add("Rest-Sign", sign);

        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MtGoxTradeCLI)";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        StreamWriter reqStream = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        reqStream.Write(post_data);
        reqStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        StreamReader respStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        String response = respStream.ReadToEnd();
        respStream.Close();

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the nonce in your signature comes last in your signature for any request that takes params, e.g. for money/wallet/history with currency USD your signature should be:

```
money/wallet/history\0currency=USD&nonce=xxxxxxxxxx
```

(the \0 is a null character, just in case you're wondering)

Also, MtGox's API seems to be in flux right now - for example, for wallet history above, we used to call:

```
BTCUSD/money/wallet/history
```

as the API endpoint, but this no longer seems to work. Now we call:

```
money/wallet/history
```

So if calls that used to work for you are now failing, take a look at that too.  But I can tell you for sure that having your nonce as the last param in your QS for your signature is critical or your API calls will no longer work.

I also recommend re-creating a new API key in MtGox -we had to do so in order for our code to work properly as well. I have a hunch that this is because MtGox's recent API changes have invalidated old keys (likely to keep trading bots at bay while they figure out how to handle them without having the bots kill their API)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortonately it doesn't help me.
I tried changing the parameter order so the nonce comes last, tried both BTCEUR/money/... and money/..., created a new API key but still get a 500 internal server error.
My other API calls still work apart from the points you mentioned.